# RN version 0.55.2 appear "React Native version mismatch"

Tags: react-native

[this is error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtWyG.jpg)

I want to Integrate react native into existing app. I have done anything by https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html, but when I run the native app with Xcode, the result is

> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] React Native version mismatch.

I try to resolve it with google , but I can't do it!

Environment:

```
leecodeMacBook-Pro-5:MyApp wj$ react-native info
    Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/wj/workspace/demo/MyApp/node_modules (10ms)
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
Node: 9.11.1
Yarn: 1.5.1
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
react-native: ^0.55.2 => 0.55.2
```

Comment: Your packager might be opened for another app, while bundling

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to upgrading your RN did you follow the update guide?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

If you did and still seeing the error

did you try to clear cache?

https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d

Comment: i know the reason. person in our group provide main.jsbundle with version 0.54.2, and 0.55.2 is my native environment, so when i run the project it appear error. it is ok that install 0.54.2 version